# Can not display .mht file in IE with IIS 7 when wrong MIME type is sent

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, mime-types

We have a page in an ASP.NET site with a link to a .MHT file so when the user clicks on the link he should be able to view the MHT file in the browser.

Problem is that it displays blank and the header that IIS sends with it is like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2012 18:45:19 GMT
```

We have on IIS the MIME-type already configured correctly as per default like this:

```
.mht    message/rfc822
```

We noticed that if we open the file by the file system in our machine, IE displays it correctly, so the problem is with the header that IIS sends with the file (we assume).

Any idea why IIS is sending this header that prevents us of displaying the MHT file correctly? Any solution?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

We think of several workarounds now: see answer by me.

*Thanks everyone!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477199/binarywrite-of-mht-file-is-not-treated-as-mht-by-ie

Comment: Thanks Tomas, but the situation indicated in that question is different from ours. We are not delivering the file from ASP.NET code, it is a direct link to an MHT file located in our server, and IIS is who delivers the file alone. And the problem is as stated: IIS is sending an incorrect Content-Type, so we also cannot set it to multipart/related as the answer to that question. Thanks.

Comment: But you can map the extension to custom handler which will do the work when IIS can't...

Comment: Thanks again, yep indeed, I have updated the question with the three workarounds we think of and we are going to use ISAPI filters, but we are going to set the Content-Type to text/html not multipart/related.

Comment: Just to be clear, you MUST send the proper content-type header, or the MHT content will not work properly. This is a security feature.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Which Content-Type header value is the correct one then? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use HTTP Handler:

   a) In web.config under system.web add a node similar to:

   ```
   <add verb="GET" path="*.mht" type="WebApplication1.Handler1" />
   ```

   b) In Handler's Code Behind, inside ProcessRequest method add this:

   ```
   context.Response.ContentType = "message/rfc822"; 
   context.Response.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.FilePath)));
   ```
2. Use ISAPI filters to change the Content-Type header before sending it to the client. You will need Windows 7 SDK for Server 2008 R2 or olrder versions of the SDK depending on your target server.
3. In Global.asax, in one of these events, change the header value of Content-Type:

   a) Application_PreSendRequestContent

   or b) Application_PreSendRequestHeaders

   Cons of this: You will intercept every call.
4. Use CGI scripting to change the Content-Type header value.

We decided to use HTTP Handler solution.

Regards,

Fabian Fernandez

Answer (score 0):

You're correct on all counts:

1) The first thing I'd look at is the local browser configuration - you've verified that IE opens the local file correctly

2) The second thing I'd look at is IIS content headers.  You're right: the correct MIME type for MS HTML (.mht) files should be "message/rfc822"; the Content-Type should be "application/octet-stream".

3) This link suggests a couple of different alternatives:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/d94c0d4e-0d32-4648-bdd6-dc3f28bb4797/

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but we already head it to that link and tried the solution offered in there with no results, problem is that the solution offered is for the client and we need the server to be able to deliver the mht file correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the .mht file located in the same web application as your asp.net application? if it's in a different web application / virtual dir / web server, you'll need to check the mime type for that specific location.

If it's in the same web application, please make sure you've checked the mime types in IIS for that specific web application, because mime types can be different between web apps and web sites on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, the MHT file is in the same web server as the ASP.NET site. And also yes, we have checked the MIME-types for the ISS server and also in the application and for the last one it says "inherited" so it is using the configuration of IIS MIME-types, which I say how we have it in the question. Thanks!